# Registering event handlers in ASP.NET Core using Udi Dahan events example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I've read raising domain events as described by Udi Dahan http://udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/. I have created the necessary interfaces and events, but I'm struggling to register my events/handlers with the DomainEvents class.

The DomainEvents class uses either a Register() method, or you can provide an instance of IContainer.

I have registered an event in .NET Cores default DI Container in my Startup file using;

```
services.AddScoped<IEventHandler<TicketWasClosedEvent>, TicketWasClosedEventHandler>();
```

Next, I think I need to do two things;

1. Get an instance of ICollection from .NET Cores DI Container so I can pass it to the DomainEvents class.
2. Change the Raise() method in Udi Dahans example because it uses the ResolveAll() method on the IContainer which in .NET Core doesn't appear to be available.

Here's a copy of the DomainEvents class to save following the link above;

```
public class DomainEvents
{
    [ThreadStatic] //so that each thread has its own callbacks
    private static List<Delegate> Actions;

    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public static void Register<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        if (Actions == null)
        {
            Actions = new List<Delegate>();
        }

        Actions.Add(callback);
    }

    public static void ClearCallbacks()
    {
        Actions = null;
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        if (Actions != null)
        {
            if (Container != null)
            {
                foreach (var handler in Container.ResolveAll<EventHandler<T>>) // ResolveAll doesn't exist on IContainer
                {
                    handler.Handle(args);
                }
            }

            foreach (var action in Actions)
            {
                if (action is Action<T>)
                {
                    ((Action<T>) action)(args);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```